# Least square estimator for $\Sigma$ in multiple multivariate regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, estimation, multivariate-analysis

How to estimate the variance and covariance matrix $\Sigma$ by least square for multiple multivariate regression. The model is expressed by
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\boldsymbol{Y_j} &= \boldsymbol{X_j\beta_j} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon_j}, \quad j = 1, 2, 3\\
\end{aligned}
\label{eq:regression}
\end{equation}

where for sample of $m$ observations $\boldsymbol{Y_j}$ is a vector of dimension $m \times 1$, $\boldsymbol{X_j}$ is a matrix of dimension $m \times (p+1$), $\boldsymbol{\beta_j} = (\beta_{0j}, \ldots, \beta_{ij})^T$ ($j = 1, 2, 3$ and $i = 1, \ldots, m$) is parameters vector and $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon_j}$ is a vector of dimension  $m \times 1$. In matrix notation
$$
\boldsymbol{Y} = \boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta} + \boldsymbol{\varepsilon}
$$
where the matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$ is given by
$$
\boldsymbol{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{X_1} & \boldsymbol{0}   & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0}   & \boldsymbol{X_2} & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0}   & \boldsymbol{0}   & \boldsymbol{X_3}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: The problem you're describing is a little bit unusual. You claim to have three separate sets of 1-dimensional data $(X_1, Y_1)$, $(X_2, Y_2)$, and $(X_3, Y_3$), with a linear relationship in each and a possible covariance matrix in the observations $Y_j$. Is this what you really mean? A much more typical situation is that there is a combined dataset $(X_i,Y_j)$ with $K$ predictors $x_i$ and $L$ responses $y_j$ (in your case $K=L=3$). Then each $Y_j$ is regressed to $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$. Could you mean this, or are you sure about the special case you're describing?

Comment: I have three linear regression and I need to estimate $\Sigma$ (variance-covariance matrix) when $\boldsymbol{Y}$ have dimension $3m\times1$, where $m$ is a sample size. I calculated $\boldsymbol{\hat{\beta}} = (\boldsymbol{X}^T\Sigma\boldsymbol{X})^{-1}\boldsymbol{X}^T\Sigma\boldsymbol{Y}$, but I need $\Sigma$.

Comment: I would understand if $Y$ had dimension $m \times 3$, but the $3m \times 1$ confuses me.

Comment: This happen due $\boldsymbol{X}$ have dimension $3m \times 3(p+1)$, because $\boldsymbol{X_j}$ ($j = 1, 2, 3$) have dimension $m \times (p+1)$.